# how to view messages from activemq queues/topic through OC tool

Tags: openshift, activemq-classic

Can we view messages from activemq queues/topic through OC tool? As of now, we can view it from jolokia console but it is too slow.Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What is "OC tool"?

Comment: Assuming that the messages are logged to stdout, you can use `oc logs -f <pod>` to watch the stdout logs in realtime.